# Array of rectangles filled with text and formulas

Tags: technical-drawing

I would like to draw in LaTeX

- rectangles regularly spaced,
- 4 lines of rectangles,
- each line containing 2 rectangles

in which I am allowed to type texts and equations. Any LaTeX code for that?

**EDIT** Specifically I would like to reproduce the following picture

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is a "line of rectangles"? And how can a line contain rectangles? For the first one you can search any TikZ guide. It's a basic feature.

Comment: Regarding your edit: So you are looking for an array which cells are partially framed. That can easily be done with a `tabular`. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try the `matrix` approach from `TiKZ`. This is just an example, but many positioning and style aspects may be added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{squarestyle/.style={draw,text width=2cm,text height=1cm}}
\tikzset{matrixstyle/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2em,row sep=2ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [%
        matrixstyle,
        column 2/.style={nodes={squarestyle}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={squarestyle}},
    ]
    {%
        Something \& A \& B \& Text \\
        Something \& A \& B \& Text \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward way can be this (obviously, you will define macros for the boxes, but this is to give an idea), [using basic LaTeX boxes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#minipage_and_parbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt\relax % no indent at the start of the paragraph
\fbox{\parbox[t][3cm][c]{5cm}{
    Some text
}}\hspace{0.5cm} %% this is the horizontal separation
\fbox{\parbox[t][3cm][c]{5cm}{
    Some text

    \[ f(x) = formula \]
}} 

\vspace{0.5cm} % and this the vertical one --- notice you star a paragraph here (blank lines)

\fbox{\parbox[t][3cm][c]{5cm}{
    Some text
}}\hspace{0.5cm}  
\fbox{\parbox[t][3cm][c]{5cm}{
    Some text
}} 

%% repeat as needed

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: output of above code]

Or ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\fbox{\parbox[c][2cm][c]{3cm}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Text \mybox{some text} \quad \mybox{$f(x)$} more text

\bigskip
Text \mybox{some text} \quad \mybox{yeap} and more text

\bigskip
To align it \mybox{you have} \quad \mybox{to use} a tabular or similar...

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image: New output]

Obviously, you can use the [package `tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) for a MUCH better look... just read the manual and try!

[image: Example from tcolorbox package]

Comment: Perhaps you should explicit mention the `tcolorbox` features for math boxes, i.e. `\newtcbtheorem` etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer perhaps I should... when I learn about them! ;-)

Comment: Well, anyway (+1) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
  \newcolumntype{f}{>{\collectcell\cellframe}l<{\endcollectcell}}
  \newcommand*\cellframe[1]{\fbox{\makebox[2em][l]{\strut#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lffl}
  something & x &    & text \\[10pt]
  something &   &    & text \\[10pt]
  something &   & xy & text \\[10pt]
  something &   &    & text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

*Note.* Of course, you can use math mode in every cell of this `tabular`.